# how to get CGI form data from the command line in C++

Tags: c++, forms, web, cgi

I'm just starting to try and learn CGI programming. I have a simple webpage with a form. The form has two input fields asking for a number.

Im just trying to figure out how to use the command line to send the numbers in the text boxes to my CGI program, multiply them, and cout the result.

WITHOUT using an external library, how do I get the input from the form?

Comment: This is a great reference... http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_web_programming.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you have to check environment for QUERY_STRING

so if CGI passes you string `some_path?var1=a&var2=b` then you could do

```
char* query = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
// query will be set to "var1=a&var2=b"

int a = atoi( ... ); // some code to find var1 and get "a" as a string
int b = atoi( ... ); // some code to find var2 and get "b" as a string

fprintf("%d", a+b);
```